# opening existing project in ADT 21

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the small project for Android, that I open usually in ADT 21 for Windows.
But there is mystery for me: when I close ADT, then I cannot open successfully my existing project, instead I should "*Import...*" it again and again into new folders, that irritates me strongly.
If I click twicely "*.project*" file, then empty ADT Eclipse is opened and there is no my project here.
File-> Switch workspace doesn't helps me too...
Does anybody have that trouble?
UPDATE: Thanks guys. With your help I discovered deeper importance of *.metadata* folder. I read somewhere, that if you had troubles with project, just delete *.metadata* and *.settings* folder. That misunderstanding force me to ask question.
So I created new project, imported there my sources and resources and stayed carefully with *.metadata* folder

Comment: How are you closing your ADT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried https://superuser.com/questions/253831/how-do-i-delete-an-eclipse-project-when-ive-already-deleted-the-folder-and-cont?

Completely remove your project from the metadata folder. Then add it again. The folder is located at

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\projects\
```